# Showing error while trying to resizing image using Sharp module [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, image, express

I want to resize an image. For that i am using nodejs and sharp module.But I am getting an error stating post requires callback function instead of object. Below is my code.

```
router.post('/uploadAvatar', 
    multer({
      dest: './public/uploads/images/avatars',
      rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return 'avatar'+Date.now();
      }
    }), function(req, res) {
      // resize image
      sharp(newPath).resize(300, 200).toFile(newPath, function(err) {
         if (err) {
           throw err;
         }
         res.json(newPath);
      });
  });
```

I am getting the following error -

```
/home/chyangba/Desktop/sharptest/sharpApp/node_modules/express/lib
  /router/route.js:196
        throw new Error(msg);
            ^

    Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as post] (/home/chyangba/Desktop/sharptest/sharpApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:196:15)
    at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as post] (/home/manoj/Desktop/sharptest/sharpApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:510:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chyangba/Desktop/sharptest/sharpApp/routes/index.js:31:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using multer incorrectly, the multer({}) returns an object not a middle-ware.

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

as you see you must call **single, array, ...** on multer object to get the middle-ware!